# Is it possible to eliminate lag in rendering the mouse location for d3?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have some code that displays an SVG item above the cursor location. I've noticed that the object lags behind the cursor by more than I'd expect if it were just a frame behind.

```js
var width = 600,
    height = 200;
var mouseLocation = [0,0];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var cursor = svg.append('circle')
    .attr("r", 2)
    .attr("fill", 'darkblue');

// update mouse location
d3.select(window).on("mousemove", () => { 
  mouseLocation = d3.mouse(svg.node()); 
});

// show mouse
d3.timer(function() {
  cursor.attr("transform", 'translate(' + mouseLocation + ')');
});
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

You can see the delay by smoothly sliding the mouse from one side to the other. The blue circle lags behind the cursor by a bit. (At least on Chrome 57 on Windows)

I've tried a couple variations including calling circle.attr within the mousemove callback function. But there's always a bit of a delay.

**Edit Things I've tried unsuccessfully:**

- setting the cursor transform in the `mousemove` event
- Checking the elapsed time since the previous `mousemove` call to only update it every 16 ms.
- `svg.style("shape-rendering", "optimizeSpeed");`
- Using the `mousemove` event for the svg rather than the window
- Using the `d3.event.pageX` and `d3.event.pageY` rather than `d3.mouse(svg.node())`
- I get the same issue using `<canvas>` [demo](http://bl.ocks.org/steveharoz/184401755e8338fa8d7f619717dd4bc6)

Comment: At the risk of being a little pedantic, you won't be able to eliminate lag; what you may be able to do is to reduce it to an acceptable level.

Comment: @andand Yes, reducing it to < 1 frame (~17 ms) is equivalent to eliminating it

Comment: Just for reference, `d3.interval(callback, 1 millisecond)` and `setInterval(function, 1 millisecond)` have the same effect, still a noticeable lag.

Comment: Similar: [*"Is there a way to reduce lagging of a guideline that follows the mouse pointer?"*](/q/12828006)

Comment: @sharoz try `d3.event.pageX/Y`. It seemed faster to me but, again, maybe it's just my eyes.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Thanks for the idea, but still very laggy.

Comment: This is probably going to keep on hauting me for days... After expanding on the demo and doing some analysis using Chrome`s timeline tools my findings are these: 1) It's not a speed issue of calculating, getting hold of event data, selecting elements and the like. These are all fast and will have long finished before the next paint is scheduled. 2) There is little delay between the mouse event and the repaint. In fact, I found not a single case, where the mouseevent hadn't been handled by the next animation frame. The measured delay from data update to repaint is typically around 8ms...

Comment: ...3) Mouse events are fired frequently; you will often find more than one mouse event between two consecutive animation frames. Therefore, I'd assume the pointer coordinates to be quite precise. 4) There is no difference in terms of repainting, whether the DOM updates are issued in the event handler itself, using `d3.timer()`—i.e. using `requestAnimationFrame`—, or via `setTimeout()`. Again, there is no blocking or bottleneck in the first place, most of the time it is in idle.

Comment: For the time being I concluded this to be an issue not of your code, nor of D3, and only partially of the browser. The rest of the lag, i.e. anything in excess of some 8ms (2-3 pixels in my normal mouse motion) I blame on delay the OS introduce when notifying the browser of pointer events. @GerardoFurtado

Comment: I retagged this to include [svg] to broaden the audience and lure Robert Longson into this ;-)

Comment: @altocumulus That's what I said in my deleted answer (when you get to 10k you're gonna see it): the issue is not on the code, nor on D3, but on the user agent.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Yes, I briefly saw that yesterday: both the original as well as the edited version. I am myself hesitating to put this into an answer of its own. Maybe you could undelete yours and turn it into a community wiki as a starter which could be expanded on gathering facts and findings. I doubt, there will be a satisfying answer to this other than "no, you can't"...

Comment: @altocumulus I'm a little busy now, but I'll undelete it and mark as CW. Fell free to edit it.

Comment: I also experimented with a guess-ahead algorithm, i.e. extrapolate ahead of the actual new position by taking the distance from the last event's position into account and add a little extra to the new position. Maybe my algorithm wasn't clever enough or the approach is flawed but the first implementation turned out to be too choppy to be a real improvement.

Comment: @altocumulus I tried making a version of this using canvas instead of svg, and I get the same problem (see new edit). That suggests it's something beyond just svg.

Answer (score 0):

In the first version of this answer (look at the edit history) I tried `d3.interval` and `setInterval`, with no difference.

However, I believe that, maybe, this question has no answer (in the sense of what OP wants), because the lag depends on D3 handling the `mousemove` event. It's also possible that the issue here is not even D3 related, but depending on how the user agent (browser) controls the `mousemove` event frequency.

This can be seen if we put the code for moving the circle inside the very `mousemove` function:

```
d3.select(window).on("mousemove", () => { 
    mouseLocation = d3.mouse(svg.node()); 
    cursor.attr("transform", 'translate(' + mouseLocation + ')');
});
```

And the lag is still the same:

```js
var width = 600,
    height = 200;
var mouseLocation = [0,0];

var svg = d3.select("div").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var cursor = svg.append('circle')
    .attr("r", 2)
    .attr("fill", 'darkblue');

// update mouse location
d3.select("div").on("mousemove", () => { 
  cursor.attr("transform", 'translate(' + (d3.event.pageX - 16) + "," + (d3.event.pageY - 16) + ')');
});
```

```html
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: I ran your code and get a similar lag. Do you not get a lag for that code?